# RoutedEventArgs cannot be founded in the System.Windows

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program on the Windows Forms (VS13). In the code:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WF
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

`RoutedEventArgs` cannot be found, but it exists in the namespace `System.Windows`. What can be reason? I have a reference to the `WindowsBase`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RoutedEventArgs` is a WPF-specific thing. In Winforms, nothing like that exists. You should remove your reference to `WindowsBase` ans stick to Winforms specific things.

For instance, the `Loaded` event doesn't exists. You must use the `Load` event from the `Form` object instead. The designer really helps here in adding all the bits of code you need and attaching the event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I did add `Windows.UI.Xaml` namespace and problem solved.

Comment: That's not a Winforms component, but a WPF one, -1.